# How to import sample project to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When i try to import the sample project in android studio from below URL of developers.android .com

http://developer.android.com/samples/RepeatingAlarm/index.html

and i getting below error in android studio

[image: android studio import problem]

What was i made mistake to import that.

Please give me suggestions to import this project.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the hyperlink and Android Studio will fix it. As you can see from screenshot it is using Android Gradle plugin 0.9.2, but require newer maybe 0.11.+ as you are using Android Studio 0.6.1

**EDIT**
Bellow is build.gradle file as you should have in RepeatingAlarmSample folder in order for application to work. Your Android SDK should be up-to-date build tools 19.1 and as I mention in comments use Gradle 1.10, 1.11 or 1.12

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+"
}
```

Comment: I have clicked that hyperlink also its showing same error only

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Well you can always go into build.gradle generated by AS and change com.android.tools.build:gradle to 0.11.+. Make sure that you have Gradle 1.10, 1.11 or 1.12 installed